# FFMPEG replace specific place in a video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, fingerprint

I have a show on my drive. In that series, there is a intro which starts randomly, one time at 2:00, second at 1:33, etc. However, I have a "custom intro" in a file. I want to replace that intro in the show. Since original intro don't start in regular time, I guess I need to use some sort of audio fingerprinting tool. Does anybody have any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Why use the audio track? Doesn't the intro have video frame to detect? Then see https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23641/finding-frames-in-video-that-match-an-image or https://superuser.com/questions/1694684/find-a-frame-in-a-video-from-an-image-using-ffmpeg or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825892/find-frame-in-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Yeah that would be easier than audio fingerprinting, however how do I can now replace that with my custom intro?

Comment: Once you found the position of the intro and you know the constant length, you can cut it with the usual tools and compose the output by concatening the part before the intro, your own intro and the part after the intro.